# How to read data from field value in real time database in Cloud functions(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to read "OrderedTime" or any other field from the below structure(Image) but i always get output as "undefined" , but when i use "Amount" field then i am getting output as "Total Amount : 10₹" , I am not sure what i am doing wrong here.

```
  exports.addCfTimeTodeliverables = functions.database.ref('/root/{VendorId}/deliverables/{key}').onCreate((snap, context)=>{
    const data = context.params.VendorId
    var requestSnapshot = snap.val().PhoneNumber;  // getting undefined  for all the fields (Not working as expected)
    var requestSnapshot = snap.val().Amount;  // getting "Total Amount : 10₹" (Working as expected)
    console.log("------->"+requestSnapshot);
})
```

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue?

[Screenshot of firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7fSr.png)

Answer (score 2):

Our function must always return something, so we can solve this error by adding

> return true;

after the last line.

From this:

```
  exports.addCfTimeTodeliverables = functions.database.ref('/root/{VendorId}/deliverables/{key}').onCreate((snap, context)=>{
    const data = context.params.VendorId
    var requestSnapshot = snap.val().PhoneNumber;  // getting undefined  for all the fields (Not working as expected)
    var requestSnapshot = snap.val().Amount;  // getting "Total Amount : 10₹" (Working as expected)
    console.log("------->"+requestSnapshot);

    })
```

To this:

```
  exports.addCfTimeTodeliverables = functions.database.ref('/root/{VendorId}/deliverables/{key}').onCreate((snap, context)=>{
    const data = context.params.VendorId
    var requestSnapshot = snap.val().PhoneNumber;  // getting undefined  for all the fields (Not working as expected)
    var requestSnapshot = snap.val().Amount;  // getting "Total Amount : 10₹" (Working as expected)
    console.log("------->"+requestSnapshot);

    return true;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample database with the same structure as yours and I got the value for `PhoneNumber`. What I noticed is that after getting that value I got the data as follows:

```json
-------> 1111111111
{"severity":"WARNING","message":"Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value"}
```

Which I suspect is the message you're getting but in any case the data in being retrieved and the other message is only a warning. Anyway, the code I used is as follows, give it a try:

```js
exports.addCfTimeTodeliverables  = functions.database
.ref('/root/{VendorId}/deliverables/{key}')
.onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const data = context.params.VendorId;
  var requestSnapshot = snap.val().PhoneNumber;
  console.log("------->"+requestSnapshot);
  
  return null;
});
```

Comment: Thanks YeriPelona, I used above code only but still getting "undefined", not sure what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: Could you please share the complete message you get?